# How can I parse homogeneous lists in FParsec?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I'm having an issue trying to parse a homogeneous json-like array in FParsec. I've decomposed the problem to a short example that reproduces it.

```
#r @"..\packages\FParsec.1.0.2\lib\net40-client\FParsecCS.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FParsec.1.0.2\lib\net40-client\FParsec.dll"

open System
open FParsec

let test p str =
        match run p str with
        | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
        | Failure(errormsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errormsg


type CValue = CInt of int64
            | CBool of bool
            | CList of CValue list

let P_WHITESPACE = spaces
let P_COMMA = pstring ","
let P_L_SBRACE = pstring "[" .>> P_WHITESPACE
let P_R_SBRACE = P_WHITESPACE >>. pstring "]"

let P_INT_VALUE = pint64 |>> CInt

let P_TRUE = stringReturn "true" (CBool true)
let P_FALSE = stringReturn "false" (CBool false)
let P_BOOL_VALUE = P_TRUE <|> P_FALSE


let P_LIST_VALUE =
    let commaDelimitedList ptype = sepBy (ptype .>> P_WHITESPACE) (P_COMMA .>> P_WHITESPACE)
    let delimitedList = (commaDelimitedList P_INT_VALUE) <|> (commaDelimitedList P_BOOL_VALUE)
    let enclosedList = between P_L_SBRACE P_R_SBRACE delimitedList
    enclosedList |>> CList
```

When I use the `test` function to try it out, I get the following results:

```
test P_LIST_VALUE "[1,2,3]"
Success: CList [CInt 1L; CInt 2L; CInt 3L]

test P_LIST_VALUE "[true,false]"
Failure: Error in Ln: 1 Col: 2
[true,false]
 ^
Expecting: integer number (64-bit, signed) or ']'
```

If I swap the order of `P_INT_VALUE` and `P_BOOL_VALUE` when using the `<|>` operator, then `[true,false]` parses successfully but `[1,2,3]` fails with a similar error. So basically, what ever parser I use first is what it tries to use.

I understand the `<|>` operator won't attempt the RHS parser if the LHS mutates the user state - but I can't see how that could be happening. P_BOOL_VALUE and P_INT_VALUE don't have any starting characters in common, so both should be failing immediately when trying to parse the wrong data type. Ints never start with 'false' or 'true' and bools never start with numeric digits.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but a quick hint is to wrap both parsers into `attempt`.

Comment: `attempt` shouldn't be necessary, and as I just tested, it doesn't fix the issue. I honestly can't find why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I've figured it out. The hint in the error message is the `or ']'`. The problem is that `sepBy` succeeds on empty input, so when it hits the `t`, it returns successfully with an empty list, and then control passes back to `between` which tries and fails to find a terminating `]`.

The solution is to move the empty list case out of the int/bool-specific parsers, like this:

```
let P_LIST_VALUE =
    let commaDelimitedList ptype = sepBy1 (ptype .>> P_WHITESPACE) (P_COMMA .>> P_WHITESPACE)
    let delimitedList = (commaDelimitedList P_INT_VALUE) <|> (commaDelimitedList P_BOOL_VALUE) <|> preturn []
    let enclosedList = between P_L_SBRACE P_R_SBRACE delimitedList
    enclosedList |>> CList
```

Note the use of `sepBy1` instead of `sepBy`, and the addition of `<|> preturn []` to handle the empty case only once in `delimitedList`.

As a side-note, I don't know your exact application, but it is generally not such a good idea to enforce typing in the parser; a more common way to implement this would be to just parse a `commaDelimitedList (P_INT_VALUE <|> P_BOOL_VALUE)` (with your original `commaDelimitedList`) and then check the typing in a subsequent analysis phase.

Comment: Success! That works! So if I understand it correctly, once the parser hits the 't' that causes P_INT_VALUE to fail. Following that sepBy assumes it is getting an empty input and succeeds. Then between tries to parse a ']' and fails? 

I actually thought about accepting a heterogeneous list in the parser then validating it in an analysis phase like you said. For some reason I thought handling it in the parser was better. What's the disadvantage of going this route?